# delegate jQuery toggle event to the rest of the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, click, toggle

I have a dropdown menu activated on click.
I use toggle to activate it when you click on the .hello_panel 
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="login_panel">
            <div class="hello_panel"> 
                <div class="hello_label">Hello </div> 
                <div class="hello_value">foofoo</div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.hello_panel').bind('click', function(){
   $('.menu_popup').toggle();
})
```

if I click it it works fine, it does the show and hide effect when the .hello_panel 
is clicked.
what I want is it to be shown if the .hello_panel is clicked and hidden back if when clicking anything else on the page except the .menu_popup

Comment: need this http://jsfiddle.net/6bo1rjrt/13/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it whenever you click on the document

JavaScript

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('.menu_popup:visible').hide();
});

$('.hello_panel').bind('click', function (e) {
    $('.menu_popup').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="login_panel">
        <div class="hello_panel">
            <div class="hello_label">Hello</div>
            <div class="hello_value">foofoo</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="menu_popup">menu_popup</div>
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/6bo1rjrt/16/

Another way if you don't want to stopPropagation is passing a call back function that registers a once time click listener to that document to hide the menu

```
$('.hello_panel').bind('click', function () {
    $('.menu_popup').show(function () {
        $(document).one('click', function () {
            $('.menu_popup:visible').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/6bo1rjrt/17/

Comment: this prevents the menu to open, I attached a console.log after the toggle and after the hide and they are printed together.

Comment: @RuvenGam it needed stopPropagation, I have update the code and added a demo